# How can I find and select/remove nearly-equal variables across data frames?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have data sets that have several nearly-equal (always the same integer, different decimal values) numbers, not in the same row across data frames/lists. Something like:

```
1.003 
5.307 
11.912 
4.586 
13.900 
2.387
```

and

```
3.050
11.954
7.319
5.605
```

I would like to have 11.912 and 5.307 returned. So far I have tried to reduce the second to a simple

```
3
11
7
5
```

before using two for loops to look for any case where 0 > df1 - df2 > 1. If this is satisfied, it should be written to a new data frame or list (I'm not picky here, this is the end of my data manipulation). df1 and df2 are single-column data frames, with df2 already truncated to integers.

```
k = 1

for(i in 1:dim(df1)[1])
  {
    for(j in 1:dim(df2)[1])
    {
      if (df1[[i]]-df2[[j]] > 0 && df1[[i]]-df2[[j]] < 1)
      {
       df3[[k]] = data.frame(ID = k, Value = df1[[i]])
       k = k + 1
      }
    }
  }
```

gives the error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". I'm sure I'm missing some syntax or something silly, but I'm still an R novice and cannot figure it out. I'm also not sure that, errors fixed, this code will do what I'm hoping. Any help would be greatly appreciated; Thanks!

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

Given the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1.003,5.307,11.912,4.586,13.900,2.387),
                 col2 = c(3.050,11.954,7.319,5.605,10.312,8.421))

> df
    col1   col2
1  1.003  3.050
2  5.307 11.954
3 11.912  7.319
4  4.586  5.605
5 13.900 10.312
6  2.387  8.421
```

We can apply the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  filter(as.integer(col1) %in% as.integer(col2)) %>%
  select(c(1))
```

Which yields:

```
> df
    col1
1  5.307
2 11.912
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortage path is load the project in any editor like wise intlelij or edit plus go to find in path serch keyword replace all